# Is this a sufficient amount of knowledge to define a unique ellipse?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, tangent-line, triangle-centres

Recently, I've been trying to work out a closed formula for the [Mandart inellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandart_inellipse) of a triangle, and I made a little plaything on Desmos to streamline the process. So far I've successfully located the splitters of the triangle and the Mittenpunkt, so I *think* I'm good to go, but I wanted to make sure just in case.

So, with that said:

> If one knows an ellipse is tangent to a triangle at three points and has a defined center, then is it sufficient to say that only one such ellipse exists?

Here, when I refer to the "center" of the ellipse, I am referring to the midpoint between the two foci, to be clear. Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using skew (axes) transformation,

$$(x',y')=(x+y\cos \omega,y\sin \omega)$$

You could always generate a two-parameter family of ellipses touching the three lines defining $\Delta ABC$,

$$
\left(
  \frac{x}{\lambda a}+\frac{y}{\mu b}-1
\right)^2=\frac{4xy}{ab}
\left(
  \frac{1}{\lambda}-1
\right)
\left(
  \frac{1}{\mu}-1
\right)$$

which touches the axes at $A(\lambda a,0)$ and $B(0,\mu b)$ and the line $\dfrac{x}{a}+\dfrac{y}{b}=1$.

For inscribed ellipse, $$\lambda,\mu \in (0,1)$$

Now the centre is

$$(X,Y)=\frac{(\lambda a,\mu b)}{2(\lambda+\mu-\lambda \mu)} \implies
(\lambda,\mu)=
\left(
  1+\frac{bX}{aY}-\frac{b}{2Y},
  1+\frac{aY}{bX}-\frac{a}{2X}
\right)$$

If $a,b>0$, then

$$\frac{X}{2a}+\frac{Y}{2b}>1 \land 0<X<\frac{a}{2} \land 0<Y<\frac{b}{2}$$

which is the interior of the [*medial triangle*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MedialTriangle.html) of $\Delta ABC$.

Please also refer to my older post [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4387522/existence-of-an-exellipse/4388045#4388045).